# EventHandler upcasting/downcasting

Tags: c#, casting, eventhandler

I've a library that defines `ConfigurationChanged` event. It used to use `EventArgs`, but I want to extend it to `MyEventArgs`, but don't want to bring BC break to customers. They shall still be able to have `EventArgs` signature to consume the event args.

It works fine as long as they assign their handling method directly. But If some of them pass `EventHandler<EventArgs>` around, then it won't assign with
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler<MyEventArgs>'`.

[Code snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pc4a1U)

```
public class Test
{
    private static event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ConfigurationChanged;

    public Test(EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        ConfigurationChanged += eventHandler; // Cannot implicitly convert
        ConfigurationChanged += OnConfigurationChanged; // Works
    }

    private static void OnConfigurationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
}
```

Would you have any workaround/best practice around that or there is no way to obey breaking change?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the type of the event is a binary breaking change whatever you do. What you've described is trying to make it not a *source* breaking change.

What you *can* do is add the more specific event as a separate event, and proxy event subscription by creating a new `EventHandler<MyEventArgs>` from the handler that's passed to the `add`/`remove` parts. Fortunately, delegate equality still works in that situation, so unsubscribing does the right thing automatically:

```cs
using System;

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
}

public class Test
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> GeneralEvent
    {
        add => SpecificEvent += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(value);
        remove => SpecificEvent -= new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(value);
    }

    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SpecificEvent;

    private void OnEvent(MyEventArgs args)
    {
        SpecificEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();

        EventHandler<EventArgs> generalHandler = (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("General");
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs> specificHandler = (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Specific");

        test.GeneralEvent += generalHandler;
        test.SpecificEvent += specificHandler;
        Console.WriteLine("Raising event with both subscribed");
        test.OnEvent(new MyEventArgs());

        test.GeneralEvent -= generalHandler;
        test.SpecificEvent -= specificHandler;
        Console.WriteLine("Raising event with both unsubscribed");
        test.OnEvent(new MyEventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is decent proposal, I will work it out from here or just bring BC break in the end. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, that's decent approach, having an adapter for old event. I will work it out whether I do transition as you proposed and breaking change right away.